# Switching the order of substituion and differentiating

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have $f(x_1, x_2, x_3):\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is sufficiently differentiable. Suppose I want to compute 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_3} f(x_1, x_2, x_3) \Big{|}_{x_i = T_i (1 \leq i \leq 3)}. 
$$
Does the order of substitution and differentiation matter here?
For example, can I do all the differentiating first then do all the substitution, or can I differentiate with respect to $x_3$ and then substitute $x_3 = T_3$, then do similarly for $x_2$ and then for $x_1$, and both results would be the same? (I won't substitute $x_i = T_i$ then differentiate with respect to $x_i$ of course...)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Well the order of substitution definitely matters. For example if you first substituted all $x_i = T_i$ before differentiating, you would be left with a constant whose partial derivatives will all be $0$. The correct order is to first differentiate and then substitute (some particular cases may perhaps turn out to work both ways, but this would require knowing more about $f$ to guarantee).

Comment: I think I understand your thought now. Suppose you first compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}$ and then substitute $x_3 = T_3$ and then perform the remaining differentiations. This is fine, because the remaining partial differentiations will treat $x_3$ as a constant anyways.

Comment: @TobErnack Any order such that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ comes before substituting $x_i = T_i$ is fine, is what I am starting to think. Is this what you mean here?